# Button stops after first click

Tags: javascript, loops, button, foreach, infinite

```
const btnEl = document.getElementById("btn")
var taraEl = document.getElementById("tara")
var capitalaEl = document.getElementById("capitala")
const rezultatEl = document.getElementById("rezultat")

let randomNr;

randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 251)

btnEl.addEventListener("click", async function(){
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
        const data = await response.json();
        rezultatEl.style.display = "block"
               
        taraEl.innerText = data[randomNr].name.common;
        capitalaEl.innerText = data[randomNr].capital;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error");
    }
})
```

Any idea how can I made the button brings another's data, without refreshing the page?
Now after I press the button, one time, the generator button is inactive.

I want to press the button and get another country, also capital, but without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only generate the random number once, when your JS first runs after the page is loaded. So it will be the same every time the button is clicked - resulting in no visible change to your page. To get a new random number each time, move these lines of code:

```
let randomNr;

randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 251)
```

(which by the way could just be one line: `let randomNr = ...`) inside your event handler function:

```
btnEl.addEventListener("click", async function(){
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
        const data = await response.json();
        let randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 251);
        rezultatEl.style.display = "block"
               
        taraEl.innerText = data[randomNr].name.common;
        capitalaEl.innerText = data[randomNr].capital;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

(using a hardcoded 251 to generate your random number is a bit weird too. Presumably that's the length of the `data` array but it's better just to write it as `data.length`, which you couldn't do in your first version - `data` is unknown at the point it runs - but you can in the above version.)